# How to define a general get() method in Slick DAO

Tags: scala, slick

I'm used to write SQL or use simple database interaction tool like Active Record. Slick has this really elaborate functional database connection concept, and I want to learn more, although just beginning.

I used play-slick and some people told me to use `trait DAO` (which has something to do with Scala Cake Pattern). Also it is said `DAO` is used to place common functions that would otherwise have been written inside `object xxx`.

Now I'm trying to write a function in `DAO` that can query data out of database based on which object is calling it, for example:

```
trait DAO extends Apple with Orange {
   val apples = new Apples //Apples is a class extending Table trait inside Apple trait
   val oranges = new Oranges //same above

   def get() = {...//some mysterious implementation}
}

Object Apples extends DAO { //companion object of Apples class
    ....
}//same for Object Orange
```

So now I can just call `Apples.get()` and get all the apples in the database, but if I call `Oranges.get()`, I can get all oranges in the database. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not make DAO an object and call DAO.apples?